# Как проверить с помощью регулярных выражений город, который введет пользователь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Нужна проверка с помощью регулярных выражений.
Каждый город должен распознаваться, если пользователь пишет его с маленькой буквы или меняет окончание (использовать регулярные выражения). Если пользователь вводит город неправильно, следует предложить ему варианты городов, в которые есть рейсы.

Написал вот такой код:

```
import re

city = 'Лондон, Париж, Москва'
user_city = 'лондоне'
if re.search(user_city,city,flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    print('cool')
else:
    print('bad')
```

Но он не ищет, если вводить другие окончания. После того, как совпало, надо еще менять значение на правильное, лондоне на Лондон...

Comment: Используйте нечёткий поиск: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy  Примеры тут где-то были вроде в некоторых ответах на SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярными выражениями такое сделать сложновато будет. Лучше использовать так называемый "нечёткий поиск":

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import re

city = re.findall('\w+', 'Лондон, Париж, Москва')
user_city = 'лондоне'
score = list(map(lambda x: fuzz.QRatio(x.lower(), user_city), city))
max_score = max(score)
if max_score > 80:
    print('cool')
    print([c for (c,s) in zip(city, score) if s == max_score])
else:
    print('fuck')
```

Вывод:

```
cool
['Лондон']
```

Хотя выбором конкретной функции нечёткого сравнения (их там несколько) и подбором коэффициента похожести, возможно, придётся поиграться.